# Metamask/Public and Private Keys

Tags: metamask

I have used Metamask to generate a ERC20 wallet i think the wallet number for deposit of coins is  the public key.I have a log in for Metamask does this produce the private key??

Answer (score 2):

If you can sign into your Metamask account, then you can also gain access to the private key.

You simply click on the ellipses (`...`) next to your account name, and click `Export Private Key`.

[image]

It will ask you to confirm your password, which if you do, will show you your private key and allow you to copy or download it.